# How to use Flux Container.create in Typescript 2.8

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flux

I'm trying to update my react/flux project from typescript 2.2 to 2.8.

I have the following defining a store using the container.create utility function:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'flux/utils';

export let MyContainer = Container.create(class extends React.Component<props, state> {
    static getStores() {
        return [/* list of stores here*/]
    }

    static calculateState(prevState: state, props: props): state {
        return {hello: true}
    }

    render() {
        return <div>something</div>
    }
}, { withProps: true });
```

If I export this component and try to use it, I get the following error:

`TS2605: JSX element type 'Component<props, ComponentState>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.`

This worked fine when I was on typescript 2.2, but after updating I get errors everywhere I try to use the container component like this.

I am using the @types/react typings version 15.0.28. [Here are the definitions for Flux Containers.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/flux/lib/FluxContainer.d.ts)

Comment: try `rm -rf node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn` from here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/21242

Comment: I'm not using yarn and this is not an issue with the stuff installed in my node_modules directory

Comment: @theycallmemorty, you can try that with npm itself if you want, best to give it a shot first when its an upgrade scenario

Comment: Can you also make sure you have `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in you `tsconfig.json`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: @theycallmemorty, any feedback on my comment or existing answer?

Comment: The answer below worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently starting with typescript 2.6 this error occurs. But I am not sure what breaking change causes this behavior, none seem to [match](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22TypeScript+2.6%22+label%3A%22Breaking+Change%22+is%3Aclosed).

The root cause is this:

```
let readOnlyOrVoid: Readonly<void | {}> // resolves to void | Readonly<{}>
let readOnlyOfAny: Readonly<any> // in 2.5 this resolves to any, in 2.6 it does not we still have Readonly<any>
readOnlyOfAny = readOnlyOrVoid; // valid in 2.5, not so in 2.6
```

Relating back to `React`, `ComponentState` is defined in 15.0.23 as :

```
type ComponentState = {} | void ;
```

While the `state` for a `JSX.ElementClass` (which extends `React.Component<any, any>`) has the type `Readonly<any>`.

Since `Container.create` will return a wrapped component with the state `ComponentState` we run into exactly this issue of assigning `Readonly<void | {}>` (from the wrapped component) to `Readonly<any>` (from the definition of `JSX.ElementClass`)

The simplest solution is to update the typings for `react` to  `15.0.39` which replaces the definition of `ComponentState` with:

```
type ComponentState = {};
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation!!

Comment: @theycallmemorty don't forget to award the bounty :D